# Empty .MOV file, stuck on iPhone

Tags: macos, ios, filesystem, iphone, image-capture

After using Image Capture to copy all my photos and movies from my iPhone to my Mac, and deleting from the iPhone, I find I have one stubborn remaining file listed in Image Capture. It has a usual name, `IMG_0155.MOV`, but the size shows as 0.

There is indeed such a movie copied to my Mac, with a normal size of 93 MB. The movie plays normally in Preview.app on the Mac.

I cannot select the file in Image Capture, so I cannot click the *Delete* button (red circle with slash).

Is there some way to get rid of this glitchy ghost file?

Comment: It'd be in the DCIM folder, right? Couldn't you just open the phone and go to that folder with Finder then find the video and delete it manually?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same mysterious problem. Easiest answer I have found that worked for me: simply delete the offending empty .mov file(s) directly from your iPhone's Photos app (select and trash). They will then magically disappear from Image Capture and Photos on your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

If the device is jailbroken, you can manually delete the file from `/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/*APPLE/`.