# Mystery MOV file on iPhone crashes share in iOS

Tags: iphone, photos, crash

Somehow this white background image file got generated on my iPhone. It shows up in the `Photos` app like the following screenshot highlights with the info details displayed.

[image: empty MOV file]

You can see it's a white background with the black text `MOV` centered in the image. What generates this file? I stumbled across this file because every time it was included in a `Share` operation it crashed the Photos app so I kept narrowing down the share range for an AirDrop transfer until image range no longer crashed. It turned out this 0x0 file was crashing the app. The curious thing is the image details states that the file is 31MB. Something buggy is going on here, does anyone know what creates this degenerate dimensioned MOV file?

Comment: I tried to play with the file, I could add a caption to the photo, adjust the date/time, add location data, still the image would not share and would crash Photos. I wound up just deleting the file in the end to remove it from Photos.

Comment: Looks like at least one other person encountered this empty MOV file showing up on their device https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196418/empty-mov-file-stuck-on-iphone